# Wrong language setting in Arch KDE

Tags: arch-linux, kde, locale

I've installed KDE on Arch Linux, everything is ok, except the language, infact after that I've installed italian language and setted that as preferred, the texts of tabs, settings and so on is mixed in american english and italian. I want use only italian and american english is available languages menu (not preferred). How could I delete american english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts that haven't been translated to italian(or any other preferred language) will be shown in US English.(if there is no other preferred language) so i think there is no way to delete that.
And here is the list of language packages and there is no US English in it so you can't remove it:
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/kde-l10n/